# Troubles with PHP Encoding

Tags: php, encoding

I'm not PHP programmer but I need to change some things for CMS (opencart)

So that is not so hard I just found how it works **Template -> Model -> View -> LanguageBase**

But when I edit (***with notepad***) Language file like

```
<?php
// Heading
$_['heading_title']    = 'Информация'; // Changed russian word (it was russian, I just changed it to another word)
?>
```

And drop it on hosting, I can see **????????** Only :( How can I deal with encoding there ?

thank you.

**Added :** seems like files is truely UTF8, when I save it as ANSII I can see ���������

Comment: Does it work fine on the same hosting before u edit? I doubt if the hosting supports the russian language?

Comment: @Roman: Hosting has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Roman - yes my Edit braked the file somehow

Comment: Use Notepad++ to open and edit your file -- much safer. Using it open another file that has Russian words and check what encoding it uses (UTF-8 or Win-1251, with BOM or not). Now open problematic file and change to the same settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you scan your files for UTF8 BOM ? 
http://emrahgunduz.com/categories/development/php/take-2-on-utf8-bom-remove-bom-with-php/

Also use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and save your files as UTF8 , don't use notepad.

Comment: Yes fixed, the BOM was a problem, converted files to UTF8 with no BOM.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you save the file as UTF-8. There's an "encoding" droplist in Notepad when you use "save as", it probably defaults to "Ansi". I'm assuming that your CMS is using UTF8, anything else would be surprising..

Comment: Also if this file is included in some other file you may need to change those files to UTF-8 as well

Comment: I just tried to save it as UTF8 - same result. (and after all UTF8 were default chose)

Comment: Check that your servers defualt encoding (in php.ini) is utf-8. If you chose "view source" on the resulting web page, do you see some line in the header indicating utf8?
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> Is your text represented correctly in the source?

Comment: there is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> and I'm not sure where I can find php.ini (if I download and upload file with no changes it works fine)

Comment: upload a file with <?php phpinfo(); ?> in it and you'll find a row about default_encoding there somewhere. How about the files that use your data, are they *all* saved as utf8? I'm not familiar with opencart I'm afraid, so I don't know how it's built. If you upload a file with just "echo ('Информация');", how does that work?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your file is encoded in UTF-8 and that your server is sending the proper `Content-Type` header. You might also want to drop in the following in the head of your document:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

You can send the proper header by using this snippet:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Also, if you are using FTP to upload your file, upload it in BINARY mode.

Comment: upload in binary mode did not helped and after all if I don't edit file just download and upload - it being fine :S